# How to create offline PDF Map with makers?

Tags: java, android, pdf, offline, marker

In front of me is the task of creating a view for displaying PDF as Map with markers, i.e. the behavior of the view should be like that of a map: add markers, zoom, moving of makers(while zooming) and click effects on the markers(to display marker info). Those. it's like an offline map from PDF.
I know how to display PDF, but I do not know how to add markers to coordinates on this PDF.

On iOS `Core Graphics` allows to make it, but what is an alternative for Android?

**Can anybody tell me how to create the view? or any lib to add markers to PDF?** Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using the libs:

https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

https://github.com/Lukle/ClickableAreasImages

The flow is: convert PDF->Bitmap->PhotoView->Add markers as bitmaps to source bitmap-> add clickareas to marker places